# How to create JSON Schema property of type string or null

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, jsonschema, ajv

My schema looks like something like this:

```
schema: {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be allowed to set string or null, How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [array to allow a property to be multiple types](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor79). The types must be one of the [seven JSON Schema primitive types](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8).

```
{
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: { type: ['string', 'null'] }
  }
}
```